# angular router not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I am trying to add some routing to my project. And I am using basic angular route with Angular 1.3.0

app.js file:

```js
'use strict';
var routerApp = angular.module('mcw', [
  'ngRoute',
  'mcw.controllers', 
  'directives',
  'filters',
  'mcw.services']);
routerApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {templateUrl: 'index.html', controller: 'LoginController'})
  .when('/Home', {templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', controller: 'ResourcesController'})
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mcw">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title spec</title>

        <script src="js/angular1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular1.3.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular1.3.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/commonFunc.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
        <script src="js/server.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I use 'python -m http.server' (Python 3.4.3) as the server, and the urls of
"127.0.0.1:8000/", "127.0.0.1:8000/index.html", "127.0.0.1:8000/index.html#/Home" all goes to index.html page.

Answer (score 5):

You have missed `ng-view` directive on page, which loads view from `$routeProvider` and the `template` & specified `controller` will get loaded in the `ng-view` element.

Add it inside body

```
<body>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I regard this as: the router just refresh the content of the which inside ng-view. Is that right?

Comment: @RTzhong Correct..content will be refresh inside the `ng-view` element

Comment: @RTzhong do you want anything else? would you accept mine answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need ng-view inside the body.

Only what you load inside the ng-view tag should not be index.html in my view. (but what you want to place inside the ng-view tag). The index.html should be the page where you place your ngview. To load other html files in (insie the ng-view tag)

The way it works is that the 'directives' will be placed INSIDE the ng-view tag.
(to be more specific, the html files you typed in your router {.when} objects.
in your case: templates/home.html  and what you called index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mcw">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title spec</title>

        <script src="js/angular1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular1.3.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular1.3.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/commonFunc.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
        <script src="js/server.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can even use a div with ng-view inside it  if you wish. (i reccomend the first method)